# document.querySelector( ).click(); not working selenium $0.click(); undefined

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, frame

I am trying to click a button with selenium. I have tried Chrome and Firefox console with $0.click(); and works but when testing with the selector it does not work, "undefined", document.querySelector("#td").click();.

I trying with selenium does not work.

HTML:

```
<td id="td" onclick="if(top.body) Len('td')" class="lenDesActiv">Date</td>
```

I tried the following:

```
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("td#tdDos.lenguetaActiva").click();')
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("td#").click();')
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("#td").click();')
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("td#td").click();')
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("td").click();')
driver.findElement(By.id("td")).click();
document.getElementById("td").addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("hello world");
});

loginelement = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'td')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", loginelement)
```

Comment: Your entire form is in an iframe switch to it first. /html/frameset/frameset/frame[2] use this xpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) with text as **Fecha** is within a `<frame>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://your_website.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"frame[name='body']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td#tdDos.lenguetaDesActiva"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://your_website.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//frame[@name='body']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[@id='tdDos' and @class='lenguetaDesActiva']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Fecha]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

First switch to the frame.

```
driver.switch_to.frame("body")
```

wait for the element to be clickable.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//td[@id="td"]')))
```

Click on element using JavaScriptExecutor.

```
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("td").click()')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue was an iframe switch to it first.

```
driver.get("https://webpage.com")
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/frameset/frameset/frame[2]"))
loginelement = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'td')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", loginelement)
```